# Was there ever a trade war between the U.S. and Canada?

Tags: united-states, trade, canada

https://www.marketplace.org/2023/12/25/canadas-planning-to-impose-a-digital-services-tax-the-u-s-government-is-not-amused/

> Now the U.S., Canada and more than a hundred other countries are
> negotiating a global digital services tax that would supersede those
> individual taxes. The U.S. tells Canada, ‘Hey, just wait for the
> global tax to be finalized. No need to jump ahead.”
>
> But Christians says any global tax deal would have to be approved by
> all of those countries’ legislatures and the U.S. Congress isn’t known
> for lightning speed.
>
> “Canada like a lot of countries is frustrated with the pace of
> international agreement and I think, wary that they may be waiting in
> vain for the U.S. to agree to something,” she said.
>
> **There are worries that tensions between the U.S. and Canada over the
> digital tax could turn into a trade war.** Daniel Bunn, the President
> and CEO of the Tax Foundation, said the U.S. could hike tariffs on
> imports from Canada.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada%E2%80%93United_States_trade_relations

> There are several disputes arising from the bilateral trade between
> the two nations. The United States placed Canada on its Special 301
> Report intellectual property rights enforcement (although under the
> mildest category of "rebuke"). Other products from Canada under
> dispute include softwood lumber, beef, tomatoes, and other
> agricultural products.
>
> The heightened border security as a result of the 2001 terrorist
> attacks has been an issue of concern for businesses in both countries.
> The issue has become less of a concern since the attacks with the
> development of new technology, registration, training, and fewer
> rules. However, a midpoint estimate of US$10.5 billion costs to
> businesses in delays and uncertain travel time have affected trade.[5]
>
> One ongoing and complex trade issue involves the importation of
> cheaper prescription drugs from Canada to the United States. Due to
> the Canadian government's price controls as part of their Single-payer
> medical system, prices for prescription drugs can be a fraction of the
> price paid by consumers in the unregulated U.S. market. While laws in
> the United States have been passed at the national level against such
> sales, specific state and local governments have passed their own
> legislation to allow the trade to continue.[citation needed]

There are mentions of trade disputes between the two about lumber, drugs and whatnot, but I haven't found any mention of an actual trade war between the two countries. I don't know what definition the article uses, but I guess a trade war is an escalating tit-for-tat in trade like the one between China and the U.S. for example.

Comment: This question should probably be on History.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lumber disputes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada%E2%80%93United_States_softwood_lumber_dispute) are a recurring theme in US Canadian trade, running from *waaaay* before Trump.

- US position:  Canadian firms get public land cheap to grow trees
- Canada position:  US unfairly restricts imports of finished wood products, but doesn't mind importing raw logs where the value gets added by US firms.

Is it a trade war?  Yes, if only on a specific product range.  Which is the case with many trade wars anyway (you more often see "x tariffs on products a, b, c from country y" than "x tariffs on all of country y's products").

[Inside the never-ending softwood lumber trade war between Canada and the U.S.](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/business/article-softwood-lumber-trade-us-canada/).

> Canada’s softwood producers say they have paid more than $8-billion in lumber duties to the U.S. from 2017 to 2022.

> Countervailing duties are levied in retaliation for alleged subsidies while anti-dumping duties are imposed for what the U.S. Department of Commerce views as lumber being sold below market value.

> “The longevity of this lumber dispute defies gravity,” said Prof. Zhang, who wrote a 2007 book titled The Softwood Lumber War.

And it can get pretty ugly when it gets going, from suffering Canadian lumber firms to US builders not getting enough wood cheaply.